# update model and association in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

To have a vague idea, having a model "Account"

```
const Chars = require('./chars');
const Account = sequelize.define('account', {
 ...
}
Account.hasMany(Chars, { as: 'chars', foreignKey: 'accountId' });
```

table chars is like:

```
id |charId     |accountId  |ival          |bval
28 |1          |90         |0             |null
29 |2          |90         |0             |null
30 |3          |90         |200           |null
31 |4          |90         |null          |true
32 |5          |90         |null          |false
33 |6          |90         |null          |false
```

so "account" has many "chars" but need them to update at once (if possible)

just need some guidance to made a proper update to the account model and rows for table "chars" (association) using sequelize.

should I use some "foreach" ? maybe a "bulkUpdate" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need all the chars for a single account to be updated at once? Use something like this:

```
Chars.update(
  {
    ival: 0, // put your value here
    bval: 0, // put your value here
  },
  { 
    where: { 
      accountId: myAccountId, // put your id here 
    } 
  }
);
```

If you mean that you want the account, and all it's associated chars, to be updated at once - well, you can't do that in a single query. You need one query to update the account, and another to update the chars.

Comment: i just want to now if possible with sequelize and have an idea how to, if nobody says the opposite i will accept your answer. thanks